# Nginx docker react ec2 https connection refused

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2

Tried a number of different versions of nginx.conf, but nothing appears to be mitigate the classic connection refused page when I enter my https://domain.

It should be noted that the domain ends with .dev, wondering if this matters.

The domain was purchased on google domains, and there are A record mappings to a public EC2 instance that has the running nginx server (inside the docker container).

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name random.dev www.random.dev;

  return 301 https://random.dev$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;

  server_name random.dev www.random.dev;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.key;

  index index.html index.htm;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17.7.1 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY ./ssl /etc/ssl

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ui:
    image: <image> 
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

EC2 instance has an Amazon Linux 2 flavor.

Security group mapping appears to be correct, with ssh (22), http (80), and https (443) accepting inbound from everywhere.

Network ACL is default (open to all, inbound and outbound).

After running docker-compose, I've also tried checking using netstat (inside ec2 outside docker) whether 80 and 443 were listening, and they were.

http on the raw IP (not domain) has worked when I commented out the 443 nginx conf code, but the domain does not work because .dev and .app automatically redirects to https on chrome (and firefox I believe).

Given this, wondering if anyone else faced any problems similar to mine. Is this an Amazon Linux 2 problem, or is it a .dev problem, or could it possibly be an ssl problem?

Answer (score 0):

A series of changes were made, but the fix appears to have something to do with assigning an elastic IP address to the ec2 instance.

For some reason the local wifi I was using (Verizon) always led to a timeout request to the IP address on `ping <ip-address>`. However, on the other networks we tested (comcast as well as ATT mobile data), the IP address was not refused. This is likely to have something to do with the IP address being blacklisted by Verizon. I am not sure if all static IPs are blacklisted or we just got unlucky. The elastic IP that was assigned seemed to fix the issue.